# mysql stored procedure to insert values, from a select statement and parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, subquery

I'm writing a stored procedure to select multiple values from a table, and then insert one each value into a new row in a different table along with two parameters which are passed into the function.

All the documentation I can find shows how to insert results selected, not insert results selected along with parameters, it's that syntax I want to know.

```
function (a, b)

select c from table
 for each result, 
    insert (a,b,c) into newtable (a,b,c)
```

In the above pseudo code the value c is retrieved from the select statement, but the values for a and b come from the stored procedures arguments. The select statement might return multiple values.

So lets say in table we have:

**id    c**
1    apple
2    orange
3    pear

Then I call the stored procedure:

```
procedure(recipe, book)
```

then we would see in newtable:

**id    a    b    c**
1    recipe    book    apple
2    recipe    book    orange
3    recipe    book    pear

Answer (score 2):

Ok I'll rewrite it as a procedure so you understand `a` and `b` are not values from table `table`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure(IN paramA VARCHAR(50), IN paramB VARCHAR(50)) 
     BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO newtable
        SELECT paramA, paramB, c
        FROM table
     END;
```

So, as in your example, you would then call it like this:

```
CALL procedure('recipe','book');
```

Comment: this adds them into new columns not rows.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by 'new columns not rows' but I rewrote it as a stored procedure so you understand better that a and b are provided as parameters.